# Kontact launches Kmail

Tags: kubuntu, window, kmail, korganizer

Kubuntu 13.04.

Launching kontact opens a separate window for kmail, which is annoying.

If I launch kontact I just want kontact to be opened. If I need just kmail I'll just launch kmail.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not happening anymore. Maybe some update has fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

**Try Hope it works,**

1. First Close System tray icons of Kmail and Akregator.
2. Then Close Kontact if open, dont just close from close button, Quit from file menu.
3. Now when all Kontact related applications are closed in system tray, open the Kontact application from Menu.

Now it will start kmail embedded within it.

Comment: Still works in 2023 with Kontact 5.19.3!

Answer (score 0):

Kontact is a PIM manager. Sound like just want want `kaddressbook`.